# add ReplyTo field in symfony when sending mail

Tags: php, email, symfony1, contacts

I am doing modifications to an existing project which is already built and one of the tasks is to add email address of person who filled the contact form in 'reply-to' field while in from field, the address is of webmaster {so that it doesnt send to spam}

**Question is, how to add reply-to field?**

the mailing class is using **sfMailer** and when I tried to use **addReplyTo()**  method (did some google and found this), then error says:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method sfMailer::addReplyTo()
```

on checking API at http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfMailer came to know there is no such method. So how does one add reply-to field? Its not a huge task but I don't know how to do it!

Comment: If you think adding a Reply-To: header will get you past a spam filter, I suggest you rethink your approach. A more correct solution would be to add a Sender: header but at the end of the day, header games will not get you very far. Only send to confirmed opt-in addresses, or have some other mechanism in place to ensure that your messages are relevant and acceptable for every recipient.

Answer (score 8):

Construct your message like this :

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
      ->setFrom('from@example.com')
      ->setTo('to@example.com')
      ->setSubject('Subject')
      ->setBody('Body')
      ->setReplyTo('reply@to.com');
$this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

`setReplyTo()` is a method of the `Swift_Message` class (inherited)

Comment: Symfony 1.4 has integrated swiftmailer, so you could use $this->getMailer() instead :-)